# How to work between Excel and PowerPoint w VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

First of all, let me just say that this is a pleasure. I've consulted this forum for years (Fortran uni assignments), but this is my first post, you guys are awesome.

I'm sort of desperate because I can only use Office products and I don't really know VBA. I'm a working student at a big company, and I know some Python, but I've never coded in an object based language such as VBA. First of all, would you recommend any tutorial out there that might help me understand VBA? I'm at a loss here.

I've been tasked with automating a reporting process. Basically, I need to create several PowerPoint presentations with tables and graphs. These all feed from **one** Excel file. This file (already done) collects data from different Excel files (automated downloads), and puts it all together.

The code I've managed to scramble together so far, using code I found on the Internet:

```
    Sub ExportaraPowerPoint()

    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim excelTable As Excel.Range
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As 

    Workbooks("def1.xlsm").Sheets("Execution Audit Plan").Activate
    Set excelTable = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:K12")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptApp = GetObject("", "PowerPoint.Application")
    Err.Clear
    If pptApp Is Nothing Then Set pptApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Appliaction")
    pptApp.Visible = True
    pptApp.Activate

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

    excelTable.Copy

    pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(link:=True).Select
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

    End Sub
```

But I'm guessing that creating a presentation (and the tables and graphs) manually and then using a VBA script to automate the data in them would be easier, but I don't know how. Do you have any ideas? I don't need code, just new ideas.

Comment: Is the PowerPoint always going to display the same graphs but just "up to date"? If yes then you can link the PowerPoint to the Excel files and have it automatically update the graphs.

Comment: Yes! But there will be several Power Point presentations. Is there a way to update both tables and graphs at the same time via VBA? Btw, thanks!

Comment: Tables and graphs will only be updated when the Excel file is open, I don't see a reason why you would need to update it from PowerPoint. In my opinion make PowerPoint update all the linked tables and/or graps when the PowerPoint is opened or on each iteration of the presentation (if it's a constant looping PowerPoint)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: If you need further help with it I'll gladly help but I just need to be sure how to help.